# PHP - check if csv line is empty

Tags: php, csv

In my code I'm reading csv file with `fgetcsv` function

```
while($line = fgetcsv($handle, 4096)){
    .....
}
```

How can check when the `$line` is empty, I mean `$line = ',,,,,,,,'` ?
**note:** I'm not always know the number of columns.

Comment: `if (trim($line, ',') == '') {`?

Comment: I've linked a very similar question that was asked a few days ago, the accepted answer will easily handle your problem with some edits

Comment: You can simply check if(!empty($line[0])){ //your logic }
$line[0] for first column, $line[1] for second column same for other

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be:

```
if (str_replace(array(',', ' '), '', $line) != '') {
  // do something
}
```

Basically, it will compare the line after you remove all comma's and spaces from the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the contents of file in an array and check which index has empty value.
like this -

```
$handle = fopen("file.csv","r");
$data = fgetcsv($handle,",");
while($data = fgetcsv($handle)) 
{
$array = explode(",",$data[0]);
print_r($array);
}
fclose($handle);
```